# Best Practices - Building an API which allows remote login

Tags: php, api, http, oauth

I'm writing an API for a service I'm building located on server A. In order to use the API websites are given an API key. The service stores username/passwords (on server A). I'm building a PHP script for website owners so people can login to the service from other servers, let's say server B.

On server B, a user will type in a username and password. This info (along with the site's API key) will be sent to the API on server A, and a response will be sent back if the login was successful.

How hard is this to do? What are the best practices here? Obviously, it is dangerous sending passwords around. How can I make this safe? Is this an OAuth situation? The logging in part isn't as important as getting info about whether the user/pass combo is valid.

Thanks

Comment: OAuth may be a good use for this

Comment: Is this for server to server communication or for browser to server communication?

Comment: Hmm not really sure. The login form will be shown in the browser and located on a different server.

Comment: You are fine sending it, I would just recommend possibly using https, POST over GET, and encrypting the password before sending to the API. This is basically how most API's work.